# Fill in the rest of this joint distribution such that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. (There are multiple answers)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$$\begin{array}{c|cc} &X=0&X=1 \\
\hline Y=0&?&3/16\\
Y=1&3/16&?\end{array}$$

I know that they are independent if $P(X=x,Y=y)=P(X=x)\cdot P(Y-y)$ but when I try to solve this I just get a mess of equations. Is there a specific way to solve these types of problems outside of playing around with algebra?
I got $x_0y_1=x_1y_0=3/16$ and $x_0+x_1=y_0+y_1=1$, but I can't make anything of them.

Comment: "I just get a mess of equations" Please show the mess you get.

Comment: The "mess" of equations can contain at most 4 equations. Write them all down (and edit the question with them).

Comment: How come you need four unknowns when you are asked to fill two empty squares?

Comment: I dont actually need to solve for $x_0,x_1,y_0,y_1$. I'm just trying to find $x_0y_0$ and $x_1y_1$, but I have the extra variables in case they offer some clue.

Comment: Sorry but I see only *one* unknown to be found, not four.

Comment: Independence requires $(X|Y=0)\sim (X|Y=1)$ which means $f_{00}/(3/16)=(3/16)/f_{11}$ where $f_{00}+f_{11}=1-3/16-3/16$. So you just need to solve quadratic $x^2-10/16+(3/16)^2$. Solutions are $1/16$ and $9/16$ by inspection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{array}{c|cc} &X=0&X=1 \\
\hline Y=0& a &3/16\\
Y=1&3/16& b\end{array}
$$

$\Pr(X=0) = a + \dfrac 3 {16} = \Pr(Y=0)$, so

$$
a = \Pr(X=0\ \&\ Y=0) = \Pr(X=0) \cdot \Pr(Y=0) = \left( a + \frac 3 {16} \right)^2.
$$
$$
a = \left( a + \frac 3 {16} \right)^2
$$
$$
256 a^2 - 160a + 9 = 0
$$
etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Let $P(X=0, Y=0) = a$ and $P(X=1, Y=1) = b$.

Now:

1. Write down the expression for $P(X=1)$ (remember to sum out $Y$).
2. Write down the expression for $P(Y=1)$.
3. Write down the equation $P(X=1,Y=1) = P(X=1)\cdot P(Y=1)$, and show us what you get.